# Android: How to determine the optimal size of the images to use as background of different views?

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources, android-drawable

When you use `drawable` resources (i.e. images) as (for example) background for different `Views` or `ViewGroups`, how do you determine the size of the image you are creating?

For example how do I know what should be the size of the image to use as a `Tab Indicator`'s background, or a `button`'s background, and then those for all the different screen sizes we have?

All the questions I have found, which discuss the sizes of images, discuss stretching image, or shrinking etc., but how do I know what will be the optimal size, and then that for all the different screen sizes?